# Telegram многоуровневое меню inlinekeyboard

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, inline

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def AllGroups(message):
    if configs.i_m == message.chat.id or configs.admin2 == message.chat.id:
        groups = MySqlGroup.groups('')
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=name) for name in (groups)])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите группу", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def inline(callback):
    users = MySqlGroup.groups(callback.data)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user, callback_data=user) for user in (users)])
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                          text="Выберите пользователя", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Есть такой код. 
Необходимо сделать многоуровневое меню, как в том же @BotFather. То есть, когда чтобы можно было переключаться дальше.
В данный момент получается так что я отображаю все группы, затем нажимаю на кнопку и появляются пользователи этой группы, но последующее нажатие на кнопку по юзеру, ничего не выдает. А должно выполняться еще одно действие. Что необходимо дописать?

Comment: Посмотри метод register_next_step_handler. К сожалению на работе гитхаб в бане, не могу зайти скопипастить

Comment: Этот метод работает только с message, насколько мне известно

Comment: Попробуй перепиши код сверху так:  
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите группу", 
    reply_markup=keyboard)  
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, callback_query_handler)  

def callback_query_handler(...)

Answer (score 0):

В общем для многоуровневого диалога нужно использовать метод register_next_step_handler, который будет осуществлять ветвление диалога. [Вот пример использования](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

код приведенный выше можно оформить так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def AllGroups(message):
    ...
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите группу", reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, inline)


def inline(message):
        ...
```

Comment: Нет, это совершенно не то, этот метод отлично работает если мы используем обычную клавиатуру, а ту которую я хочу использовать работает с callback и таким вариантом она не передается

Answer (score 0):

Сделал inline кнопки через огромное кол-во `elif`, не знаю правильно это или нет, но большое подозрение падает на то, что это не правильно. Однако работает.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def inline(callback):
    groups = MySqlGroup.groups('')

    users = MySqlUsers.UsersName()
    print(users)

    if callback.data == 'Группы':

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=name) for name in (groups)])
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                              text="Выберите группу", reply_markup=keyboard)

    if callback.data in groups:
        print(callback.data)
        usersInGroup = MySqlGroup.groups(callback.data)
        if usersInGroup == []:
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user, callback_data=user) for user in ['Назад']])
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                                  text="Нет пользователей в {group}".format(group=callback.data), reply_markup=keyboard)
        else:
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=user, callback_data=user) for user in (usersInGroup)])
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                                  text="Выберите пользователя", reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif callback.data in users:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        global USER
        USER = callback.data
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=choose, callback_data=choose) for choose in ['Пароль', 'Информация']])
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                              text="Вывести пароль пользователя или информацию?", reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif callback.data == 'Информация':

        user = MySqlUsers.UserInfo(USER)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                              text="Пользователь: {data} \nУстройства:\n{userInfo}".format(data=USER, userInfo=user),
                              reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif callback.data == 'Пароль':
        password = MySqlUsers.UsersPassword(USER)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id,
                              text="Пользователь: {data} \nПароль: {passInfo}".format(data=USER, passInfo=password),
                              reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif callback.data == 'Назад':
        callback.data = 'Группы'
        inline(callback)
```